# How to scroll to element with Selenium WebDriver (when using headless mode)

Tags: c#, selenium, headless-browser

I hope you are all having a good day. I'm trying to get my code working with Selenium but nothing is working out for me. I am using headless mode with chromedriver and Selenium in C#. I am trying to scroll to a certain element, because without doing this I cannot click a certain element. I have tried both actions to scroll to this element and JS but neither of these seem to be working when using headless, while this works fine without. Does anybody have an idea on what could work? Thanks!

**EDIT**:

Thank you, marked solution seems to work as far as scrolling to elements go. I'm still facing an issue when the content (a song on Spotify) isn't being played in headless, elements to play the song succesfully get clicked, but the song doesn't actually play, which I can see by echoing the playtime into the console. When not using headless this works completely fine. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**:

Turned out the issue was something completely unrelated, DRM does not work in headless mode. Which means Spotify is unable to play songs when in headless.

Comment: It seems like you need a certain element to load. Have you looked into how to wait for elements to load? Something like this: https://intellipaat.com/community/5115/selenium-webdriver-wait-for-complex-page-with-javascript-to-load

Comment: Can you post your code so we can see what is going wrong?

Comment: Issue has been fixed, but I've asked a question regarding the same topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding these arguments to your driver instance:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options .addArguments("--headless")
options .addArguments("--window-size=1920x1080")
options .addArguments("start-maximised")
options .addArguments("--no-sandbox")
options .addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work as far as scrolling to elements go. I'm still facing an issue when the content (a song on Spotify) isn't being played in headless, elements to play the song succesfully get pressed, but the song doesn't actually play, which I can see by echoing the playtime into the console. When not using headless this works completely fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this to use headless and scroll to an element.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("--headless");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

var elem = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("something"));
driver.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", elem);
```

Comment: Sadly this does not seem to work, will try the other solution posted here soon. I am already using this method when not using headless.